# Getting a random element from a Collection

Tags: java, sorting, collections, random-access

in java I would like to be able to maintain my Collection of fishes sorted by species at all time (hence the use of a HashMap) while being able to pick a random element from all species except one with constant time complexity. For example the following code does the job but with O(number of elements) complexity :

```
import java.util.*;

HashMap<String, ArrayList<Fish>> fishesBySpecies = new HashMap<>();

// Insert some fishes...
// Fish has a String attribute that describes its species
// Now we want to pick a random Fish that isn't from the unwantedSpecies

String unwanted = "unwanted species";
ArrayList<Fish> wantedSpecies = new ArrayList<>();
for (String species : fishesBySpecies.keySet()) {
    if (!Objects.equals(species, unwanted)) {
        wantedSpecies.addAll(fishesBySpecies.get(species));
    }
}

// Finally !
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(wantedSpecies.size());
Fish randomElement = wantedSpecies.get(randomIndex);
```

Any idea how to do this with constant time complexity if possible ? Thanks !

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry about that, I edited my question and then forgot about the initial title, it is fixed now.

Comment: Of course, this is not possible with constant time complexity. But apparently, you are fine with an answer that just rewrites the code to look more complicated by using the Stream API, not even mentioning time complexity…

Comment: @Holger Finally I found a solution with O(number of species) using the Map, but it is too specific to my requirements for me to evoke it. I believe it wouldn't be likely to help other people. I accepted the first answer because it helped me to understand better what I was trying to do.

Comment: Your question does already have O(number of elements), as you even said yourself. So if you don’t want a better time complexity, which is as said impossible anyway, then it’s not clear what you are asking for. Picking a random element without an intermediate `ArrayList` is possible, if you want that, just ask the right question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are performing is filtering, and when filtering you have to check each element whether they need to be taken out or not. You could try to use alphabetical sorting on the keys and stop filtering once the key is alphabetically larger than your filtering (unwanted) key.

Your code can also be thoroughly shortened by using java streams:

```java
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Fish>> fishesBySpecies = new HashMap<>();

// Insert some fishes...
// Fish has a String attribute that describes its species
// Now we want to pick a random Fish that isn't from the unwantedSpecies

String unwanted = "unwanted species";

fishesBySpecies.keySet().stream() // Get the keyset and create a stream out of it
        .filter(key -> !key.equalsIgnoreCase(unwanted)) // If key is not equal to unwanted then leave it in else remove it
        .forEach(filteredKey ->
                wantedSpecies.addAll(fishesBySpecies.get(filteredKey))); // For each key that was left in, we fetch the fishes
```

OR

```java
fishesBySpecies.keySet().stream() // Get the keyset and create a stream out of it
        .forEach(key ->
                {
                    if(!key.equalsIgnoreCase(unwanted))
                    {
                        wantedSpecies.addAll(fishesBySpecies.get(unwanted));
                    }
                }
                ); // iterate and filter at the same time. Faster.
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would consist in maintaining an `ArrayList<Fish>` as well as the map you already have. There is a drawback though: adding or removing fishes would be slightly more complex:

```
Map<String, List<Fish>> fishesBySpecies = new HashMap<>();
List<Fish> wantedFishes = new ArrayList<>();

//...

public void addFish(String species, Fish fish) {
    List<Fish> speciesFishes = fishesBySpecies.get(species);
    if (speciesFishes == null) {
        speciesFishes = new ArrayList<>();
        fishesBySpecies.put(species, speciesFishes);
    }
    speciesFishes.add(fish);
    // also maintain the list of wanted fishes
    if (!unwantedSpecies.equals(species)) {
        wantedFishes.add(fish);
    }
}
```